# how to move div scroll position based on button click in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll, scrollbar, angular2-template

in app.component.html file i have one div element with horizontal scroll and two buttons as Next and Previous. based on these button click i want to move scroll.

**app.component.html**

```
<div id="th-infinite-scroll-tracker" style="overflow-y:scroll; height: 200px;" scrollTracker (scroll)="onScroll($event)" (mouseup)="searchLog($event)">
        <div *ngFor="let log of arr; let i = index" innerHTML="{{log}}" [id]="i"></div>
</div>
<button (click)="onPreviousSearchPosition()" [disabled]="disablePreviousBtn">Previous</button>
<button (click)="onNextSearchPosition()" [disabled]="disableNextBtn">Next</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll(event){
    this.scrollObject = event;
}
onPreviousSearchPosition(){
    this.disableNextBtn = false;

    this.scrollObject.target.scrollTop = 20 * --this.idCount;
  }
onPreviousNextPosition(){
    this.disableNextBtn = false;

    this.scrollObject.target.scrollTop = 20 * ++this.idCount;
  }
```

using above code we can move the scroll but we need scroll event object which will get after scrolling manually.
Please suggest me, how to create scroll event object in component class

Comment: you have a lot of scroll objects which one do you need?

Comment: when we scroll manually then we get $event object like above in code as onScroll(event){
    this.scrollObject = event;
}

Comment: Please suggest me, how to create scroll event object in component class? - this.scrollObject = event;

Comment: we get scroll event object when we scroll manually from browser page div area. then  (scroll)="onScroll($event)" will call from app.component.html page

Comment: so why it doesn't work

Comment: it will work, but i want scroll object without scroll manually from web page. because before clicking Next and Previous button we have to scroll once manually.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is how you scroll the div element - https://plnkr.co/edit/2v0iVgkOZfISqlFAkrNX?p=preview

example:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div #panel style="overflow-y:scroll; height: 20px;" >
      <div *ngFor="let log of arr; let i = index" innerHTML="{{log}}" [id]="i"></div>
    </div>
    <button (click)="onPreviousSearchPosition()">Previous</button>
    <button (click)="onNextSearchPosition()">Next</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  public arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
  @ViewChild('panel', { read: ElementRef }) public panel: ElementRef<any>;

  public onPreviousSearchPosition(): void {
    this.panel.nativeElement.scrollTop -= 20;
  }

  public onNextSearchPosition(): void {
    this.panel.nativeElement.scrollTop += 20;
  }
}
```

Comment: @YogeshUkale if it works then accept the answer so that any visitor can pay attention to it :)

Comment: HI @rusev what should I do if I want to disable buttons at scroll end. Can you please help

Answer (score 12):

I would prefer to use [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method. This method provides smooth scrolling transition effect in the browser when we click on the corresponding element.

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <div #panel class="some-class">
        <div *ngFor="let log of arr; let i = index" innerHTML="{{log}}" [id]="i"></div>
      </div>
      <button (click)="moveToSpecificView()">Move</button>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
    @ViewChild('panel') public panel:ElementRef;

    public moveToSpecificView()(): void {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.panel.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end', inline: 'start' });
        });
    }

  }
```

Comment: Do not use setImmediate, as it's non-standard. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate